# is there a way to detect when external js has loaded and executed?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there anyway to determine when an external script has loaded AND executed? I know that we can determine when it has been loaded using the `onload`event like this:

```
<script src=script.js async></script>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].onload = function(){...}
</script>
```

But what about loaded and executed?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the onload may fire before the script is parsed? Reference? I wouldn't have expected this (although a simple workaround would be to set a timer to flag parsing from the onload event handler).

Comment: Yes I get undefined variable error if I try use them after the onload event(variables are inside the external script)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method to load multiple JS scripts using jQuery deferreds and $.ajax method. Message on console will be printed when BOTH JS files are loaded & executed

Demo http://jsbin.com/qumojobawe/2/edit?html,js,output

```
var deferreds = [];

var jsFiles = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-debug.js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.js'];

$.each(jsFiles, function(idx, url) {
  deferreds.push(jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true
  }));
});

deferreds.push($.Deferred(function(deferred) { $(deferred.resolve); }));

$.when.apply(this, deferreds).done(function() {
  console.log("KnockoutJS & MomentJs is loaded", ko, moment);
});
```

If script loads additional components and does not initialize immediately you can use following wait() method which will wait until certain condition is met by rechecking it on specified interval

```
var wait = function (condFunc, readyFunc, checkInterval) {
    var checkFunc = function () {
        if (condFunc()) {
            readyFunc();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(checkFunc, checkInterval);
        }
    };
    checkFunc();
};
```

For example, following code will check when current time number of seconds ends with zero every 10 milliseconds and executes function when condition is true:

```
wait(
function() { return new Date().getSeconds() % 10 == 0 }, 
function() { console.log("this will be called when time is 0, 10, 20, 30, etc seconds", new Date()); }, 
10);
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/fayenigixo/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about script, that you can modify, then you can write a callback function in external script. You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

If you are asking about external script, that you can not modify, then you should read API documentation, if it exists. For example, here you can find a YouTube's API docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Functions

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a namespace is "loaded" with a method like this :

```
var isNamespaceDefined = function(moduleName) {
    var fields = moduleName.split('.'), cur = window;

    for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
        if(typeof cur[fields[i]] === "undefined") return false;
        cur = cur[fields[i]];
    }
    return true;
};
```

usage : `isNamespaceDefined("my.module.function")`

Combined with a setTimeout to check the loading:

```
var doWhenReady = function(){
    if(isNamespaceDefined("my.function")){
        // redefining the function;
        var _myFunction = my.function;

        my.function = function(){

            // do things Before the call

            _myFunction.apply(null, arguments);

            // do things After the call

        };
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(doWhenReady , 100);
    }
}
```

A simple solution, but may be added with some time check and error callback

Comment: I would indeed like to know whether there is a solution w/o a setTimeout. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you can't have a callback in your js file, wait for something happens is the only way

Comment: The problem is that the function I want to execute uses a variable which is set only after an element in the Dom is found. Even if I execute the function immediately after I defined it in the external script it'll throw error that the variable(which I 20 lines ago set to document.getElem...) is not defined. That's why I need to know exactly when script is executed and cannot rely on timeouts since of such variables there are dozens and check whether each of them is defined is not a solution.

Comment: I edited, maybe it can help. You should provide more informations about what you want to achieve in your post

Comment: @Hacketo Create a promise that waits for the script element's 'load' or 'error' event. Once either of those two are called, then check. Some errors will emit the 'error' event while others will emit the 'load' event even though your script was never run.